# javascript regular expression match all

Tags: javascript, regex

there is a string like

```
<img src="images/_attachments/07-08.jpg" style="width: 520px; height: 693px;" /><img src="images/_attachments/09-11.jpg" style="width: 520px; height: 693px;" />
```

I wanna get the image path `'images/_attachments/07-08.jpg'`, `'images/_attachments/09-11.jpg'` and file name `'07-08.jpg'`, `'09-11.jpg'` in javascript with regular expression.

So I code like

```
var str='<img src="images/_attachments/07-08.jpg" style="width: 520px; height: 693px;" /><img src="images/_attachments/09-11.jpg" style="width: 520px; height: 693px;" />'
var strPattern=new RegExp('<img.*?src="(.*\/(.*?))".*?>', 'g');
var arrMatch=new Array();
var strHTML='';

while(arrMatches=_strPattern.exec(str)){
    strHTML+='<div>'+arrMatches[2]+'</div>';
}

$('body').html(strHTML);
```

but all i get is path, not file name, how can i fix this?

Comment: you need to make another pattern for it

Answer (score 1):

Your path-matching is greedy, so you won't get the desired results for the file name. If you make it non-greedy, it will only match `images/`, so you either need to double it or make your filename matcher include no slashes. Change your pattern to

```
var strPattern=new RegExp('<img.*?src="(.*?\/([^/"]*))".*?>', 'g');
//                                        ^
```

Btw, a regex literal `/<img.*?src="(.*?\/([^\/"]*))".*?>/g` would look better.

Comment: sorry, i try this and it still display 'images/_attachments/07-08.jpg', not 07-08.jpg!

Comment: Ah, I see. Fixed that now, too.

Answer (score 1):

With this you are not matching the " or the >, maybe it helps?

```
var strPattern=new RegExp('<img [^>]*src="([^>"]+\/([^>"]+))"[^>]*?>', 'g');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern to match attribute contents:

```
_strPattern=new RegExp('<img.*?src="([^">]*\/([^">]*?))".*?>', 'g');
```

I you use '.' instead of '^">', the regex might span a few tags.

You also need to use `_arrMatches[1]` instead of `_arrMatches[2]` to get the full path.